# Payment information from JavaScript to Django views

Tags: javascript, python, django

I integrating a payment processor for my django app and now if payment was successful, I have a call back function written in JavaScript inside of the HTML and that gives me the transaction reference id. I want to send that reference id to my Django views for final verification.

I have tried almost all related solutions here on Stack Overflow none seems to solve my exact problem. The only thing I can do is to `console.log()` the reference id.

Here is my code

inside html

```
<script>
function payWithPaystack(){
  var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
    key: 'pk_test_somekey',
    email: 'customer@email.com',
    plan: "PLN_testcode",
    metadata: {
       custom_fields: [
          {
              display_name: "Mobile Number",
              variable_name: "mobile_number",
              value: "+2348012345678"
          }
       ]
    },

    // if transaction was successful 
    callback: function(response){
        var ref_ = response.reference
        console.log(ref_)
    },
    onClose: function(){
        alert('window closed');
    }
  });
  handler.openIframe();
 }
</script>
```

django views.py

```
def payment(request):
    # here a variable will be capture the ref_
    return render(request, template, context={})
```

Comment: Use ajax
https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write ajax call inside your callback function.

```
function PaymentCompleted(){
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url :"/payment-completed/",
            data:"reference_id=reference_id_here",
            datatype:"json",
            error:function(data){alert('Error:'+data);}
            success:function(data){alert('OK!'+data.message+','+data.code);}
          });
        }
```

And at Django views:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
def paymnet_completed(request):
    print "ajax request called"
    print request.GET['reference_id']
    return_dict = {'message': 'Payment Successful','code':200}
    json = simplejson.dumps(return_dict)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/x-javascript")
```

I Hope this might have helped.